# Subtract the values of one column for records coming from two different selections that are not necessarily the same

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a simple statement of the problem:

Assume that we have issued a SELECT query that has outputted something like this:

```
student_id |  course_id  | status_id | created_at
     1            1            1       some_date1
     2            1            1       some_date2
     6            2            1       some_date3
```

And another SELECT query on the same table that has outptted something like this:

```
student_id |  course_id  | status_id |     created_at
     1            1            3       some_other_date1
     2            1            2       some_other_date2
     4            3            2       some_other_date3
```

So, both tables are in fact temporary tables.

I want a SQL query (I'm using MySQL) that takes both selections, considers only what is in common between both selections based on student_id and course_id and outputs student_id, course_id and the time difference between created_at values for each record.

Any help is appreciated. Even a clue about some SQL capability that I don't know of is appreciated.

Comment: Does each your query provides `(student_id, course_id)` uniqueness within the rowset?

Comment: @Akina Yes, that sounds like a good solution. Yes, I believe that ```(student_id, course_id)``` determines a row uniquely in each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT student_id, course_id, DATEDIFF(t1.created_at, t2.created_at) difference
FROM (
       SELECT student_id, course_id, /* status_id, */ created_at
       FROM /* the rest of query 1 */ 
     ) AS t1
JOIN (
       SELECT student_id, course_id, /* status_id, */ created_at
       FROM /* the rest of query 2 */ 
     ) AS t2 USING (student_id, course_id)
```

Comment: Should it be "as difference" after DATEDIFF()? Does DATEDIFF() return the difference between two dates in seconds?

Comment: @stressedout *Does DATEDIFF() return the difference between two dates in seconds?* No, in days. If you need the difference in seconds then use `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t1.created_at, t2.created_at)`. Of sourse you my use another time period unit easily. PS. Does the difference in seconds between dates, not datetime/timestamp, may make sense?

Comment: Your solution seems correct to me and it makes sense overall. But I'm still processing it in my head. Why are you commenting out status_id and then use USING at the end? Will I run into trouble if I don't comment it out?

Comment: @stressedout *Why are you commenting out status_id* It is not used in outer query - so its selecting makes no sense. *use USING at the end?* This is a variant of joining condition syntax, but, rather than ON, it gives one copy of a column in output/expressions when no table alias specified whereas ON will give "ambiguous name" error. *Will I run into trouble if I don't comment it out?* No. You will only increase the amount of work for server and the amount of memory needed - without any profit.